# How To Convert Rows Into Column In Single Select Query SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How to return the following result on single select query.

Table

```
Rn  TicketNo    CreateDate               Assigned
1   xxx         2016-11-17 03:45:46.000  Tom
2   xxx         2016-11-18 03:45:46.000  Jerry
1   yyy         2016-11-17 03:45:46.000  Tom
2   yyy         2016-11-18 03:45:46.000  Jerry
```

Expected Result

```
TicketNo    AssignedToTom             AssignedToJerry
xxx         2016-11-17 03:45:46.000  2016-11-18 03:45:46.000
yyy         2016-11-17 03:45:46.000  2016-11-18 03:45:46.000
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I tried all 4 and it works perfect unfortunately stack overflow only accepts one solution to be selected.Anyway I up voted you all. You guys are awsome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This: replace  with name of your table

```
select a.ticketno
        ,a.CreateDate as [AssignedToTom]
        ,b.CreateDate as [AssignedToJerry]
         from <tablename> a join <tablename> b 
         on a.assigned='Tom' and b.assigned='Jerry' 
         and a.ticketno=b.ticketno
```

Comment: i think is it best solution for it. nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Pivot Query. Simply replace table name '#temp' to Your 'table name'

```
            select distinct  TicketNo,Tom as AssignedToTom,Jerry as AssignedToJerry
            from
            (
               select distinct TicketNo,CreateDate,Assigned 
               from #temp
            ) src
            pivot
            (
              max(CreateDate)
              for Assigned in (Tom, Jerry)
            ) piv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ticketno,
       MAX(case when Assigned='Tom' 
                then createddate else null END) as AssignedToTom,
       MAX(case when Assigned='Jerry' 
                then createddate else null END) as AssignedToJerry
from yourtab
group by ticketno
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
     TicketNo 
    ,(Select CreateDate from TicketDtl where TicketNo= A.TicketNo and Assigned='Tom')as AssignedToTom
    ,(Select CreateDate from TicketDtl where TicketNo= A.TicketNo and Assigned='Jerry') as AssignedToJerry
From TicketDtl as A
Group by TicketNo
```